# alguien me dice porque esta mal esos metodos

Tags: java

hola buenas alguien me puede ayudar nose porque no funcionan los siguientes metodos:
El 1 sirve para calcular el total de aprobados.
Cuando lo ejecuto sale 0 aprobados aunq le haya dado un valor superior a 5

el 2 metodo tampoco se que le puede fallar o faltar, cuando lo ejecuto de la misma manera me da 0

```
//Este sirve para calcular el total de aprobados
    public static int totalAprobados(double[] vector) {
        int contadorAprob = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {
       if (vector[i] >= 5) {
                contadorAprob++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Hay " + contadorAprob + " aprobados");
        return contadorAprob;
    }
//este para decirnos cuantas notas con el mismo nombre(por ej: cuantos "suficente") hay en el array
    public static int notasIguales(double[] vector, String nLetras) {
        int contadorIgual = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {
            if (NotaEnLetras(vector[i]).equalsIgnoreCase(nLetras)) {
                contadorIgual++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Hay " + contadorIgual + " iguales");
        return contadorIgual;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double vector[] = new double[10];
        double nota;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Da una nota");
            nota = sc.nextDouble();
        }
        Array.totalAprobados(vector);
        Array.notasIguales(vector, "Suficiente");
    }

}
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Por el contrario, cuéntanos tú, por qué dices que un método está mal y el otro no? Qué se supone que deberían hacer? Con qué datos los pruebas? Por cierto, añadir basura a la pregunta en vez de explicar bien el problema, no te va a ayudar

Comment: Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.
Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante 
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta). 
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!

Answer (score 0):

ya he conseguido arreglarlo el problema estaba en el for del main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        double vector[] = new double[10];
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Da una nota");
//Hay q asignarle el valor de la nota al vector de i para almacenarla en el array
            vector[i]= sc.nextDouble();
            Array.NotaEnLetras(vector[i]);
        }
```

Comment: Me parece que tu programa va a dar un Exception.